# Timer code that can run in background

Tags: android, android-service, android-background, android-timer

I want a timer code that can run in background and only stops when I want to. Basically, there are two buttons. Start timer and stop timer, and when I press the start button it starts the timer and it should automatically run in the background also, there is a TextView in the activity where I can view the timer counting down but it should not reset when I restart the application and must synchronize with the background service. And if possible, the app should notify me even when I am at my home screen when the timer finishes counting down.

Comment: use AlarmManager and PendingIntent.

Comment: have you tried countdown timer ?

Answer (score 0):

Example of how to create a long running timer service that survives activity destruction by moving to the foreground, and back to the background when a new activity bind to it.

https://gist.github.com/mjohnsullivan/403149218ecb480e7759